# How to get all form data as object array like please not use jquery ID or class selecter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to get all form data as object array like please not use  ID or class Select

Output like

```
Birthday_Day = [{"1":"1"}, {"2","2"}]
Birthday_Month = [{"January":"Jan"}, {"February":"Feb"}, {"March":"mar"}]
Gender = [{"Male":"Male"}, {"Female":"Female"}]
Course = [{'B.CA':'1'}, {'B.Com':'2'}. {'B.Sc':'B.Sc'}]
table = [
  {
    "first_name": "Jill",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "age": "50"
  }, {
    "first_name": "Eve",
    "last_name": "Jackson",
    "age": "94"
  }
]
```

Here is my form 
https://codepen.io/roshanpatel88/pen/KzaNBM

```
<h3>STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
<table align="center" cellpadding = "10">

<!----- First Name ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>FIRST NAME</td>
<td><input type="text" name="First_Name" maxlength="30"/>
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Last Name ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>LAST NAME</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" maxlength="30"/>
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Date Of Birth -------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>DATE OF BIRTH</td>

<td>
<select name="Birthday_day" id="Birthday_Day">
<option value="-1">Day:</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>

<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>

<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>

<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>

<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select id="Birthday_Month" name="Birthday_Month">
<option value="-1">Month:</option>
<option value="January">Jan</option>
<option value="February">Feb</option>
<option value="March">Mar</option>
<option value="April">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">Jun</option>
<option value="July">Jul</option>
<option value="August">Aug</option>
<option value="September">Sep</option>
<option value="October">Oct</option>
<option value="November">Nov</option>
<option value="December">Dec</option>
</select>

<select name="Birthday_Year" id="Birthday_Year">

<option value="-1">Year:</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>

<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>

<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Email Id ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>EMAIL ID</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email_Id" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>

<!----- Mobile Number ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>MOBILE NUMBER</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Mobile_Number" maxlength="10" />
(10 digit number)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Gender ----------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>GENDER</td>
<td>
Male <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" />
Female <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Address ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>ADDRESS <br /><br /><br /></td>
<td><textarea name="Address" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<!----- City ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>CITY</td>
<td><input type="text" name="City" maxlength="30" />
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Pin Code ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>PIN CODE</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Pin_Code" maxlength="6" />
(6 digit number)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- State ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>STATE</td>
<td><input type="text" name="State" maxlength="30" />
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Country ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>COUNTRY</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Country" value="India" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>

<!----- Hobbies ---------------------------------------------------------->

<tr>
<td>HOBBIES <br /><br /><br /></td>

<td>
Drawing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Drawing" value="Drawing" />
Singing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Singing" value="Singing" />
Dancing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Dancing" value="Dancing" />
Sketching
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Cooking" value="Cooking" />
<br />
Others
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Other" value="Other">
<input type="text" name="Other_Hobby" maxlength="30" />
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Qualification---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>QUALIFICATION <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td>

<td>
<table>

<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Sl.No.</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Examination</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Board</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Percentage</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Year of Passing</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Class X</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassX_Board" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassX_Percentage" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassX_YrOfPassing" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Class XII</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassXII_Board" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassXII_Percentage" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ClassXII_YrOfPassing" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Graduation</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Graduation_Board" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Graduation_Percentage" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Graduation_YrOfPassing" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>Masters</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Masters_Board" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Masters_Percentage" maxlength="30" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Masters_YrOfPassing" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td align="center">(10 char max)</td>
<td align="center">(upto 2 decimal)</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>

<!----- Course ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>COURSES<br />APPLIED FOR</td>
<td>
BCA
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" value="BCA">
B.Com
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCom" value="B.Com">
B.Sc
<input type="radio" name="Course_BSc" value="B.Sc">
B.A
<input type="radio" name="Course_BA" value="B.A">
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Submit and Reset ------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: could you add the markup to the question? Your links don't work here/for me.

Comment: a quick shot: `Object.fromEntries([...document.querySelectorAll("form [name]")].map(({ name, checked, value=checked }) => [ name, value ]));`

Comment: can you write the proper syntex

Comment: thanks for comment but we require  -> all value of a elements likeBirthday_Day = [{"1":"1"}, {"2","2"}]
Birthday_Month = [{"January":"Jan"}, {"February":"Feb"}, {"March":"mar"}]
Gender = [{"Male":"Male"}, {"Female":"Female"}]
Course = [{'B.CA':'1'}, {'B.Com':'2'}. {'B.Sc':'B.Sc'}]
table = [
  {
    "first_name": "Jill",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "age": "50"
  }, {
    "first_name": "Eve",
    "last_name": "Jackson",
    "age": "94"
  }
]